# How to check if json api data array item exists

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

In my registration i wanna check if email exist or not. If the email exist I want to show the user this email exists message.
Else to move registration process.
So it's moving directly to the registration and email already exist.

Here is my code

```
CheckEmail() async{
 var response = await http.get(Uri.parse("http://0.0.0.0:8080/index.php/path=users/"));
 var data = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
 for(var a in data){
 var email = a["email"];
 if(email == _emailController.text){
   EasyLoading.showError("this email already exist please choose onother one");
   }else{
   SaveUserData();
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> check response isEmpty or isNotEmpty

```
checkEmail() async{

 var response = await http.get(Uri.parse("http://0.0.0.0:8080/index.php/path=users/"));
var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
if(data.isNotEmpty){
for(var a in data){
var email = a["email"];
if(email == _emailController.text){
  EasyLoading.showError("this email already exist please choose onother one");
  }else{
 SaveUserData();
 }
 
}

}
```